# How to test if JSRuntime method ran in Blazor using bUnit?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, bunit, blazor-jsruntime

I have this method and I want to write a bUnit test to check whether the InvokeVoidAysnc() got called.

[image]

I have the button click for the Onclick event and I have it so that the if statement is true:

```
// Assert
            var cancelButton = cut.Find("#cancel");
            cancelButton.Click();
```

Comment: Use `await` maybe? `await InvokeVoidAysnc("window.close");`

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case the problems stems from the fact that you don't await your call:

```cs
public async Task OnCancel()
{
  // ...
  await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.close");
}
```

With that and your given test you would receive the following error:

```
Bunit.JSRuntimeUnhandledInvocationException: bUnit's JSInterop has not been configured to handle the call:

Bunit.JSRuntimeUnhandledInvocationException
bUnit's JSInterop has not been configured to handle the call:

    InvokeVoidAsync("window.close")

Configure bUnit's JSInterop to handle the call with following:

    SetupVoid("window.close")
```

So bUnit tells you how to setup your test to make it work.

```cs
JSInterop.SetupVoid("window.close").SetVoidResult();

cut.Find("button").Click();
```

You can find more on the official website: https://bunit.dev/docs/test-doubles/emulating-ijsruntime.html?q=jsinterop

EDIT:

Generally speaking, you don't want to have code that produces side effects in your unit tests (like `Environment.Exit`). A common pattern is to create a wrapper around this logic:

```cs
public interface IProgramExit
{
    void Exit();
}

public class ProgramExit : IProgramExit
{
    public void Exit() => Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

This then can be used inside your component:

```
@inject IProgramExit ProgramExit
...
@code {
    public async Task Cancel()
    {
        if (...) await JSInterop.InvokeVoidAsync("window.close");

        ProgramExit.Exit();
    }
}
```

Obviously you have to register this in your Program.cs:

```cs
Services.AddScoped<IProgramExit, ProgramExit>();
```

In the bUnit test, you can just register a mock or a fake, that does absolutely nothing. With the given async adjustments discussed earlier, you should be able to test every aspect.
}
}

Comment: With my invoke method, the application is exited when the cancel button is clicked. Is there a way to still verify the method was called or is manual testing the only way? @Link

Comment: For sure what you can do is to create a humble object around Environment exit. I will adopt my answer.